# problems defining time when pulling data from sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, time, charts

i have a problem getting the right setup for pulling data from a database.

i need to pull the last 10 minutes of data, and put it into a chart. i have 2 problems with that, i cant seem to get the arguments to work to get a specific time period (last 10 minutes), but i did manage to just grab the last 600 entries.

that works, but my chart X-axis is the wrong way, and i cant seem to find a way to invert the data in the table, after i pull it out of the database. (newest reading left and then getting older as you go further right on the chart)

the code i am using at the moment is this (yes  it's ugly and borrowed from all over) but i hope you can look past it since this is my first time coding anything like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb
import time

global variables
speriod=(15)-1 
dbname='/var/www/sensors.db'

def printHTTPheader():
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

def printHTMLHead(title, table):
    print "<head>"
    print "    <title>"
    print title
    print "    </title>"

    print_graph_script(table)

    print "</head>"

#current_time=time.time()

def get_data(interval):

conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
curs=conn.cursor()

if interval == None:
    curs.execute("SELECT * FROM readings")
else:
#         curs.execute("SELECT * FROM readings")
    curs.execute("SELECT * FROM readings ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT "+str(600))
#        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM readings WHERE time>=datetime('now','%s minutes')" % interval)

rows=curs.fetchall()

conn.close()

return rows

def create_table(rows):
chart_table=""

for row in rows[:-4]:
    rowstr="['{0}', {1}],\n".format(str(row[2]),str(row[5]))
    chart_table+=rowstr

row=rows[-1]
rowstr="['{0}', {1}]\n".format(str(row[2]),str(row[5]))
chart_table+=rowstr

return chart_table

def print_graph_script(table):

chart_code="""
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['windspeed', 'temperature'],
%s
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'windspeed'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>"""

print chart_code % (table)

def show_graph():
print "<h2>Windspeed Chart</h2>"
print '<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>'

def show_stats(option):

conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
curs=conn.cursor()

if option is None:
    option = str(24)

curs.execute("SELECT timestamp,max(windspeed) FROM readings WHERE time>date('now','-%s hour') AND time<=date('now')" % option)
#    curs.execute("SELECT timestamp,max(windspeed) FROM readings WHERE timestamp>datetime('2013-09-19 21:30:02','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('2013-09-19 21:31:02')" % option)
rowmax=curs.fetchone()
rowstrmax="{0}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{1}C".format(str(rowmax[0]),str(rowmax[1]))

curs.execute("SELECT timestamp,min(windspeed) FROM readings WHERE timestamp>time('time','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=time('current_time')" % option)
#    curs.execute("SELECT timestamp,min(temp) FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('2013-09-19 21:30:02','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('2013-09-19 21:31:02')" % option)
rowmin=curs.fetchone()
rowstrmin="{0}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{1}C".format(str(rowmin[0]),str(rowmin[1]))

curs.execute("SELECT avg(windspeed) FROM readings WHERE timestamp>time('now','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=time('current_time')" % option)
#    curs.execute("SELECT avg(temp) FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('2013-09-19 21:30:02','-%s hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('2013-09-19 21:31:02')" % option)
rowavg=curs.fetchone()

print "<hr>"

print "<h2>Minumum temperature&nbsp</h2>"
print rowstrmin
print "<h2>Maximum temperature</h2>"
print rowstrmax
print "<h2>Average temperature</h2>"
print "%.3f" % rowavg+ "C"

print "<hr>"

print "<h2>In the last hour:</h2>"
print "<table>"
print "<tr><td><strong>Date/Time</strong></td><td> 
<strong>Temperature</strong></td></tr>"

rows=curs.execute("SELECT * FROM readings WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','-1 hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('now')")
#    rows=curs.execute("SELECT * FROM temps WHERE timestamp>datetime('2013-09-19 21:30:02','-1 hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('2013-09-19 21:31:02')")
for row in rows:
    rowstr="<tr><td>{0}&emsp;&emsp;</td><td>{1}C</td></tr>".format(str(row[0]),str(row[1]))
    print rowstr
print "</table>"

print "<hr>"

conn.close()

def print_time_selector(option):

print """<form action="/cgi-bin/webgui.py" method="POST">
    Show the temperature logs for  
    <select name="timeinterval">"""

if option is not None:

    if option == "6":
        print "<option value=\"6\" selected=\"selected\">the last 6 hours</option>"
    else:
        print "<option value=\"6\">the last 6 hours</option>"

    if option == "12":
        print "<option value=\"12\" selected=\"selected\">the last 12 hours</option>"
    else:
        print "<option value=\"12\">the last 12 hours</option>"

    if option == "24":
        print "<option value=\"24\" selected=\"selected\">the last 24 hours</option>"
    else:
        print "<option value=\"24\">the last 24 hours</option>"

else:
    print """<option value="6">the last 6 hours</option>
        <option value="12">the last 12 hours</option>
        <option value="24" selected="selected">the last 24 hours</option>"""

print """        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Display">
</form>"""


def validate_input(option_str):
if option_str.isalnum():
    if int(option_str) > 0 and int(option_str) <= 24:
        return option_str
    else:
        return None
else: 
    return None

def get_option():
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
if "timeinterval" in form:
    option = form["timeinterval"].value
    return validate_input (option)
else:
    return None

def main():

cgitb.enable()

option=get_option()

if option is None:
    option = str(24)

records=get_data(option)

printHTTPheader()

if len(records) != 0:
    table=create_table(records)
else:
    print "No data found"
    return

print "<html>"
printHTMLHead("Raspberry Pi Wind Logger", table)

print "<body>"
print "<h1>Raspberry Pi Wind Logger</h1>"
    print "<hr>"
    print_time_selector(option)
    show_graph()
    show_stats(option)
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"

    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

the database contains 7 rows (unix time, date, time, windspeed, direction, temperature, checksum) it's data comming from an ultrasonic wind sensor, i would like to get the "options" in this working aswell like the max wind speed or the average wind speed, but i think that should become clear once i figure out how to actualy get the time sorted.

edit:

here is a reading pulled from the database

```
1540300313.94403|23/10/2018|21:11:53|0.1|273|24.1|5E*4B
```

and part of the code to store data in the database

```
 cursor.execute('''insert into readings values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',
 (timestamp, current_date, current_time, windspeed, direction, temperature, checksum));
 dbconnect.commit()
```

Comment: Show some sample rows from your data, and table definition. I'm guessing you're making the common mistake of using the wrong format for your timestamp column, but without actually seeing it that's just a guess.

Comment: here is a reading pulled from the database

    1540300313.94403|23/10/2018|21:11:53|0.1|273|24.1|5E*4B

Comment: here is a reading pulled from the database

    1540300313.94403|23/10/2018|21:11:53|0.1|273|24.1|5E*4B

and part of the code to store data in the database

     cursor.execute('''insert into readings values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',
     (timestamp, current_date, current_time, windspeed, direction, temperature, checksum));
     dbconnect.commit()

Comment: Yeah, my guess was right. Trying to compare a number against a string does not work well. Read over https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html